# BroadcastReceiver asynchronous onReceive

Tags: android, usb, broadcastreceiver

As the title says, is there a way to run `BroadcastReceiver onReceive()` method asynchronously?

Based on its implementation, android runs the `onReceive()` method on the main thread.

I am using the `BroadcastReceiver` to explicitly request permission to communicate with a USB device. When the request permission dialog box has received permission, the `onReceive()` method is called, but since it runs on the main thread, there is no way (at least, not that I know of) to signal when it is complete. Polling on a boolean flag would block the main thread, which in turn would block the `onReceive()` method from being called.

Is there a way to async call the `onReceive()` or is there an alternative way to explicitly (without using intent filters in the manifest) request permission and connect to a USB device?

Edit: I would like it such that the method blocks until permission is acquired and connection is established.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a partial async behavior of what you wished.

Starting with Honeycomb, you can call [**goAsync()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#goAsync%28%29), and then you have 10 seconds or so to do your work asynchronously  .

Example of usage can be shown [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22741384/878126).

Answer (score 1):

You can send a broadcast in onReceive of your broadcast receiver. The broadcast intent can be registered in Activity's lifecycle methods and can be unregistered in the same.

Comment: Yes that is a solution, but (see edit) I would like to block until I have permission.

Comment: "When the request permission dialog box has received permission, the onReceive() method is called". Isn't that your receiver receives the broadcast when the permission has been granted?

Comment: Yes that is correct, when permission is acquired, the `UsbManager` broadcasts the `PendingIndent` and the receiver calls the `onReceive()` and checks the intent extras. But this runs on the main thread.

Comment: you can always start a new thread in onReceive method and return immediately.

Comment: But during synchronization (using a Semaphore) the main thread will block and the `onReceive()` would never get called.

Comment: You can disable/enable your Receiver programmatically using PackageManager's method setComponentEnabledSetting(..).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't do anything that blocks on the main thread. Second, unless you use  `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter, String, Handler)` you should never do anything that takes much time in `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive` since it will most likely be killed after 10 seconds (see the [documentation for BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)). You should start an `AsyncTask` or a separate thread from the `onReceive` method. If you want to stop interaction with the rest of the UI until the USB device is connected, do so without blocking the main thread. Explicitly disable things or switch to some simple Fragment or Activity with a loading GIF or anything besides blocking. Blocking on the main thread will cause the wait-or-kill system dialog to pop up, and no user ever selects wait.

The simple answer to your question is to register the receiver programmatically using `registerReceiver` instead of using the manifest, but I had to provide some disclaimers first.